Opentelemetry Collector (mode: daemonset) is failing when enabling the `k8sattributes` processor
So getting this error
failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:opentelemetry:oteld-collector" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope: Azure does not have opinion for this user.
After further investigation, both ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding exists for listing Pods for that ServiceAccount
Maybe I suspect that Azure Kubernetes Service is doing something funny! Have anyone faced this if so how did you solve the issue?

try enabling the insecure setting on the processor. Apparently they don't use the k8s CA for the kubelet SSL, so it fails like that. It could be unrelated, but I've seen that as a problem that manifests this way.


failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:opentelemetry:oteld-collector" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope: Azure does not have opinion for this user.


When the ServiceAccount does not have the necessary permissions to list Pods at the cluster scope then that above error will occurs, despite the existence of ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding.

Check that the ClusterRole inbuilt has the necessary permissions to list Pods.
kubectl describe clusterrole <ClusterRoleName>

Output:
Name:         oteld-collector-role
Labels:       app=opentelemetry
Annotations:  created-by=kubernetes-admin
PolicyRule:
  Resources                                Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                                -----------------  --------------  -----
  pods                                     []                 []              [list, get, watch]

ClusterRoleBinding:
kubectl describe clusterrolebinding oteld-collector-binding

Output:
Name:         oteld-collector-binding
Labels:       app=opentelemetry
Annotations:  created-by=kubernetes-admin
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  oteld-collector-role
Subjects:
  Kind            Name             Namespace
  ----            ----             ---------
  ServiceAccount  oteld-collector  opentelemetry

ServiceAccount:
kubectl get serviceaccount oteld-collector -n opentelemetry -o yaml


Recheck the ServiceAccount specified in the error (system:serviceaccount:opentelemetry:oteld-collector) is the same one that the ClusterRoleBinding is binding to the ClusterRole.

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: oteld-collector
  namespace: opentelemetry
secrets:
  - name: oteld-collector-token-7f89g


Issue resolved, the logs indicating successful pod listing.


Result:

